# How to remove header and line numbering from algorithmic?

Tags: algorithmic, pseudocode

I created a pseudocode algorithm like this:

[image]

```
% Pseudo code %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algdef{SE}{Begin}{End}{\textbf{begin}}{\textbf{end}}
```

---

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Pseudocodice algoritmo Apriori}
\label{alg:pseudoApriori}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\floatname{algorithm}{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Begin
    \State $L_{1} = \{Frequent - 1itemset\} $
    \State $k \leftarrow 2$
    \While {$L_{k-1} \neq \phi$}
    \State $Temp \leftarrow candidateItemSet (L_{k-1})$
    \State $C_{k} \leftarrow frequencyOfItemSet (Temp)$
    \State $L_{k} \leftarrow compareItemSetWithMinSup (C_{k}, minsup) $
    \State $k \leftarrow k + 1$
    \EndWhile
    \State \Return L
    \End
\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}
```

Now I'd like to remove the header (above the first line of code) and remove the line numbering; How could I do these two things easily (being a latex/algorithmc newbie)?

The thing is I'd like to use this kind of style not only for writing algoritms but for random lines of code too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why did you  write a caption text, if you don't want a header?

Comment: Hi @Bernard , ty. I actually changed my mind about how to display code/algorithms in my tex; In the precedent style caption was needed but now I'd like to remove them. You want me to edit question?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the caption just don't write a caption command.  To remove line numbers, omit the option argument `[1]` at the `\begin{algorithmic}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algdef{SE}{Begin}{End}{\textbf{begin}}{\textbf{end}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Begin
    \State $L_{1} = \{Frequent - 1itemset\} $
    \State $k \leftarrow 2$
    \While {$L_{k-1} \neq \phi$}
    \State $Temp \leftarrow candidateItemSet (L_{k-1})$
    \State $C_{k} \leftarrow frequencyOfItemSet (Temp)$
    \State $L_{k} \leftarrow compareItemSetWithMinSup (C_{k}, minsup) $
    \State $k \leftarrow k + 1$
    \EndWhile
    \State \Return L
    \End
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to remove the border next, i would like to do that.

Comment: @LancePollard That is really a separate question, but just use the `plain` option to the `algorithm` package (standard is `ruled`, other possibility is `boxed`).