# Hide line numbers in latex algorithm

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove \EndIf
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\LinesNumberedHidden{
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{$Game PrvInd_{G,\phi}$}
\label{pseudoPSO}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Garble}{f_0, f_1, x)0, x1} 

    \If{$f(\phi(f0) \neq\phi(f1)$} 
    \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    \If {$ev(f_0, x_0) \neq ev(f_1, x_1)$}
    \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    \If{$\{x_0,x_1\} \nsubseteq \{0,1\}^{{f_0}.n}$} \Return $\perp$ \EndIf
    $(F, e, d) \leftarrow Gb(1^k, f_b)$; 
    $X \leftarrow En(e, x_b)$
    \Return (F,X, d) 
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}}
\end{document}
```

How to hide line numbering in latex `algorithm`?

Comment: So I guess this answer helped? [Undefined Control sequence for `\IF`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366332/5764)

Comment: The MWE produces undefined control sequence error for `\LinesNumberedHidden` and further errors due to the missing math in `f_0, f_1, x)0, x1`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364548/15925

Comment: \LinesNotNumbered also works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you could remove the "`[1]`" in the line "`\begin{algorithmic}[1]`"?

Comment: `\LinesNumberedHidden` seems to be a made up command

Comment: What's the downvote for? The suggestion actually works!

Comment: Thanks for editing! I totally forgot that there is such a thing as code blocks...

Comment: Simplest answer and worked well :)